# Keep the content of a div

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c

I've got a div which has a content named `level0` (`<div id="level0">`). Unfortunately `level0` changes in my webpage and I need the reuse the `div` with the same first value.

How can I achieve this?

### Edit

My code:

```
<body onload ="init()">
          <h1>Search engine bêta version</h1>
      <input id="text" type="text" size="60" value="Type your keywords" />
      <input type="button" value="Display the results" onclick="check();" />

      <script ="text/javascript">

      function check() {
          var div = document.getElementById("level0");   // Here level0 takes the value of Type your keywords and I want it to stick with the first value
          div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
      }

     </script>

      <div id="level0"> // The value I want to keep
      </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I think we'll need a little description and some code to answer this one!

Answer (score 0):

If want to use the first "text" for which you had displayed results this code may be useful

## Search engine bêta version

```
  <script ="text/javascript">
var i=1;
var firstText;
  function check() {
  if(i==1)
  {
    firstText=document.getElementById("text").value;
  }
      var div = document.getElementById("level0");   // Here level0 takes the value of Type your keywords and I want it to stick with the first value
      div.innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value;
      i++;
      alert(firstText);
  }

 </script>

  <div id="level0"> // The value I want to keep
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'd like to stick with the first value of level0 (before I type any text).

Answer (score 0):

The code below should solve this for you. On the first time it replaces, it will store the original content, and then each time it changes the text in the div, it will prepend it with the original content.

```
<body onload ="init()">
      <h1>Search engine bêta version</h1>
      <input id="text" type="text" size="60" value="Type your keywords" />
      <input type="button" value="Display the results" onclick="check();" />

      <script ="text/javascript">
      //Whether or not we're replacing the content in the div for the first time
      var firstReplace = true;
      //The original content of the div
      var originalContent;
      function check() {
        var div = document.getElementById("level0");   // Here level0 takes the value of Type your keywords and I want it to stick with the first value
        //Check if this is the first time
        if (firstReplace) {
            //Is the first time, so store the content
            originalContent = div.innerHTML;
            //Set firstReplace to false, so we don't overwrite the origianlContent variable again
            firstReplace = false;
        }
        div.innerHTML = originalContent + ' ' + document.getElementById("text").value;
      }
     </script>

      <div id="level0"> // The value I want to keep
      </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work : the first level0 stays on the page but as soon as I click another content appears under level(0) (the value of Type your keywords).

Comment: Ah I think I mis-understood your question. So when you say "Here level0 takes the value of Type your keywords and I want it to stick with the first value", do you mean you want to stick with the first value of the input box (with id of "text"), or the first value of the div (level0)?

Or do you mean that you want to create another div, rather than just replace the content of "level0"?

Comment: I want it to stick with the first value of the div (level0).